# Prove that the mean of two vectors has a lower norm than the vectors

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

The problem is: Let $E$ be a normed space. For any $x,y\in E$, with $x\neq y$ and $\|x\|=\|y\|$, show that
$$
\left\|\frac{x+y}{2}\right\|<\min\{\|x\|,\|y\|\}.
$$
When E is an inner product space this is easy to verify. The problem is that I can't prove this to E just normed. This is information that I need to complete the solution of a Functional Analysis exercise.

In the exercise, E is a Banach space. It may be that this is necessary.

Comment: If $E$ is strictly convex then this is true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not true in general. In $\Bbb R^3$, take $\|(x,y,z)\|=\max\{|x|,|y|,|z|\}$. Now, take $x=(1,1,0)$ and $y=(0,1,1)$. Then $\|x\|=\|y\|$, $x\ne y$ and$$\left\|\frac{x+y}2\right\|=\min\{\|x\|,\|y\|\}=1.$$